# And before my eyes rot

Tags: meaning-in-context

*Morton: I got on board in sight of the Atlantic. **And before my eyes rot**. I want to see the blue of the Pacific outside that window.*

Source: https://subslikescript.com/movie/Once_Upon_a_Time_in_the_West-64116

This is the line from the script of the movie Once upon a time in the West. I‘m not sure whether the script is transcribed correctly. For example the above line. Do you find the passage in bold meaningful? Maybe not "rot" but "road" but also in this case the meaning is given the context dubious.

Comment: The speaker boarded on the east (Atlantic) coast, and is headed for the west (Pacific) coast. It's a long way and they want to get there in a reasonable amount of time, to see that ocean "before my eyes rot" (the organs of sight).

Comment: Perhaps he is implying 'before I die'?

Comment: The script lacks any context or intonation. Consider the exasperated "Can you serve our meal before my tongue shrivels?"

Comment: Yes, "rot" works here as the verb. "Before my exes rot" is the time clause. I'm dunce…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When someone dies, their whole body rots, including their eyes.

The speaker boarded on the east (Atlantic) coast, and is headed for the west (Pacific) coast. It's a long way and he wants to get there in a reasonable amount of time. At least, before he dies.